# Код не выходит из машины состояний

Tags: python, aiogram, state, aiogram-3.x

Есть машина состояний `buy_item`, которая в последнем состоянии ожидает от пользователя фото чека. Нужно сделать так, чтобы у пользователя написавшего `/cancel` в момент пребывания в состоянии `Buy_item.check` . В итоге, сообщение о том, что я отменил заказ есть, но если я после этого скину ему фото, он его все равно перешлет на другой аккаунт.. Получается из состояния он все таки не выходит?
Исходный код

```
@router.callback_query(Buy_item.order)
async def item_buy (callback: CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    data = await state.get_data()
    data = data["order"]
    print(data)
    number = db.get_info(callback.from_user.id)
    print(number)
    await callback.message.answer(
        f'Заказ номер {number} открыт! Чтобы отменить его, напишите /cancel\nОплатите на карту Сбербанка по номеру +79956663556 и пришлите чек.\nВ описании фотографии напишите Имя и фамилию',)
    await state.set_state(Buy_item.check)



@router.message(Buy_item.check and Command('cancel'))
async def canccel_but (message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.clear()
    await message.reply('Вы отменили покупку товара!')
    #Запрос к базе данных (удаление ордера)



@router.message(Buy_item.check and F.photo)
async def verify_buy (message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    #Пересылка сообщения другому человеку (по user_id указанному заранее)
    await message.send_copy(chat_id=1061467560)
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вместо:

```
@router.message(Buy_item.check and F.photo)
async def verify_buy (message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    #Пересылка сообщения другому человеку (по user_id указанному заранее)
    await message.send_copy(chat_id=1061467560)
```

Следующее:

```
@router.message(F.photo, Buy_item.check)
async def verify_buy (message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    #Пересылка сообщения другому человеку (по user_id указанному заранее)
    await message.send_copy(chat_id=1061467560)
```

Проверил у себя, работает, в случае с

```
@router.message(Buy_item.check and F.photo)
```

фильтр реагирует как на State Buy_item.check, так и на F.photo

Comment: Есть пара вопросов. В случае с реагированием на фото, все в порядке. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы код срабатывал только при условии, когда оба фильтра положительны?

Comment: @router.callback_query(F.data == 'changes', userstate.HasUserIDFilter()) - вот скопировал прямо со своего кода, здесь фильтр реагирует только когда дата коллбека соответствует значению 'changes' И когда userstate.HasUserIDFilter() имеет значение True. То есть, через запятую.

Comment: UPD: Прямо сейчас еще раз проверил, действительно пропускает только при значении True в обоих фильтрах, при записи через запятую.